# How in c++ create message similar to snprintf and just change value in message?

Tags: c++

How can I create a message similar to snprintf ( where I can have generic text with %d for integer and just when I need to show in sprintf connect with parameter), to avoid concatenation? 
(I need to create result string something like `You need more %d coins`, at the moment I am doing on bad way to concatenate  and return value   `'You need more' + some_stringified_value + 'coins'`)

Comment: You can use snprintf in C++ as well, cannot you?

Comment: [Boost::Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "canonical" C++ way is to use `stringstream`, something like this:

```
std::string somefunc(int number)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "You need " << number << " more coins";
  std::string str = ss.str();
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ***can*** use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) in C++ as well:

```
int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );
```

For example (from the aforementioned link):

```
/* snprintf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer [100];
  int cx;

  cx = snprintf ( buffer, 100, "The half of %d is %d", 60, 60/2 );

  snprintf ( buffer+cx, 100-cx, ", and the half of that is %d.", 60/2/2 );

  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The half of 60 is 30, and the half of that is 15.
```

Comment: @Mgetz I thought it said printf() and not snprintf(), which I edited and corrected. He also didn't ask for "why it would be a better choice", thus me not providing such an answer.

Comment: the "why it would be a better choice" is me, like I said, I will downvote any C answer to a C++ question unless the poster can provide a very good reason they are not remaining germane to the question and providing an answer in C.

Comment: @Mgetz I understand. I hope you know, however, that a downvote is for "This answer is not useful." rather than "My personal opinion is that I don't like the answer." :P

Comment: I know which is why I downvoted you, like I said I consider your answer to not be germane to the question, and thus not useful.

Comment: @Mgetz And considering the question was "How in c++ create message similar to snprintf to avoid concatenation", I would say that it most certainly DOES have to do with snprintf(). But, fair enough. You seem to know more than I about C/C++, so I respect your opinion in the matter as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34997/discussion-between-mgetz-and-ricky-mutschlechner)

Comment: Also, just for clarity to anyone else: I'm NOT at all trying to say that this is the best practice for C++. The user asked if there is something LIKE snprintf() - what better than snprintf() itself? If anyone has a better answer, you are most certainly welcome to post it too. That is, after all, what this site is here for!